# Apache doesnt read .htaccess on a laravel application

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

I have an admin panel that written on laravel 8.
The root directory of the laravel is projectfolder, not public.
but both directory has .htaccess. I'm running this on a VPS with Ubuntu 20.04, Apache/2.4.41  and php7.4.3 (have installed all the necessary extensions) and installed ssl using certbot.

**.htaccess contents from the root project folder**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# cors
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

```
<Files .env>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```

**.htaccess contents from the public folder**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# cors
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

**My apache admin.example.com.conf contents**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName admin.example.com
    ServerAlias admin.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/admin.example.com

    <Directory /var/www/html/admin.example.com/ >
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =admin.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**My admin.example.com-le-ssl.conf contents**

```
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName admin.example.com
        ServerAlias admin.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/admin.example.com
 
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**Tried the followings**

1. Added AllowOverride All
2. Enabled rewrite module along with expires
3. Changed <Directory / > to AllowOverride All in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
4. Set APP_DEBUG=false in .env
5. Provided user permission www-data for the .htaccess file.

The front page loads fine. But when I click the Ready ? then Start button, 404 appears. Can anyone provide a solution for this as am a complete beginner?

[Console error messages](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1g2VWUkikV1gXgIHyr5VDOWkmqF_S_Vjh?usp=sharing)

Comment: Why aren't you using `public` folder as `DocumentRoot` ? What is the package you are using ? I see it goes to `step1`, should it be `example.com/step1` and work ? Is that URL correct ?

Comment: Yes it should goes to https://admin.example.com/step1 and work. And about the root directory, I tried with public but the  css files didnt load and page was broken.

Comment: Okay, that should be a different issue, but you have to always point your `DocumentRoot` to `public` folder... You can also try running `php artisan route:list` and see what are the final urls.

Comment: It's an admin panel, and it needs to check for some files permission and then finally generate required DB files. But when I set the root directory to public, I can't move to the next page.  I can only move to the next pages if the projectfolder is set as root directory.

Comment: I used this script on nginx, and set the project folder as projectfolder, it installed perfectly and worked fine. But when a request send from a web panel to admin panel, it throws 404. I tried to convert the .htaccess contents to nginx rules but couldnt get it to work. Then I decided to change to Apache. Here I tried to broke the .htaccess file just to make sure the rewrite module is working fine, just added text on top of the .htaccess file, it didn't show 500 error.

Comment: Check here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1g2VWUkikV1gXgIHyr5VDOWkmqF_S_Vjh?usp=sharing

I have attached the results of the php artisan route:list command in the name of 1111 and 2222

Comment: I see you have `step1` and `step2` in your `route:list` command. You **MUST** use `DocumentRoot` and point that to `public`. It must do it that way. Give me the errors that you are getting, but you must point it to `public`.